# Linq to SQL select distinct and sum

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a table that holds daily statistics on product QC. I need to produce a weekly report on which products passed/failed QC.

I can get the data using:

```
Dim productsPassed = (From p In dc.tblProductStats
                      Where p.StatDate >= startDate And p.StatDate <= endDate And p.Status = "PASS"
                      Order By p.Product)
```

As this is a list of daily stats I get the following by using p.Product and p.PCount columns

ASD 1
ASD 1
ASD 4
FGG 1
FGG 5
HMD 1
JWC 1
JWC 3 .... etc

I need this to be :
ASD 6
FGG 6
HMD 1
JWC 4 ....

I've tried using Select p.Product Distinct but can't figure out how to sum up the count of p.PCount

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Based on Ric's code I have tried to convert so that I still have a list which I later use a For Each product In productsPassed and build up a html table using StringBuilder.

The code I now have is

```
Dim ProductsPassed = (From p In dc.tblProductStats
                              Where (Function(p) p.StatDate >= ReportStartDate AndAlso p.StatDate <= ReportEndDate AndAlso p.PStatus = "PASS")
                              Group By (Function(p) p.Product)
                              Select (Function(p) New With {.Product = p.Key,
                                                            .PCount = p.Sum(Function(item) item.PCount)}))
```

Originally I had **GROUP** on its own and VS complained it expected **BY** so I added that and now it complains it expects an **INTO**. Also I'm not sure where **item** came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested and hazarding a guess at your structure):

```
Dim ProductsPassed = dc.tblProductStats.   
    Where(Function(p) p.StatDate >= startDate AndAlso
                   p.StatDate <= endDate AndAlso p.Status = "PASS").
    GroupBy(Function(p) p.Product).
    Select(Function(p) New With {
        .Product = p.Key,
        .Count = p.Sum(Function(item) item.PCount)
    })
```

Using some sample classes I made up produces the following output
[image]

Comment: Ric... Thanks - as you can see I'm not an expert in Linq I've updated my code using your example but still have issues. Any other suggestions.

Comment: Sure what issues do you have?

Comment: I've tried to use your code by assigning the result to ProductsPassed as shown in my update above. The code is stating that I need an INTO in my GROUP BY syntax.

Comment: Try it now, just copy and paste the query and replace your own. looks like your'e mixing method syntax and query syntax

Comment: Ric... many thanks... worked a charm... now I need to work out what its doing :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you look at it line-by-line: 1) apply the filter using `where`, 2) group by the `Product`, 3) project each element to an anonymous type with two properties, the first uses the `Key` which is the product from the grouping on line 2, the second performs a `sum` of each item on the `PCount` property