# sum datatable column DISTINCTLY with LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I would like to add to the linq query i have attached another parameter (another 'andalso' statement) for summing CleanedEquipment column. because those records are not unique.
so in order to do it i have another column "Spcall" so i need to query it DISTINCT how can i do it? (couldent find answer to that in the net).
my Datatable (dt) look like that:

[image: SpCall BillingStatus BillingYear CleanedEquipment]

```
  sumAll_SalesMoney = dt.AsEnumerable() _
           .Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("BillingStatus") = "close" _
                   AndAlso x.Field(Of Integer?)("BillingYear") = currentYear) _
           .Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer?)("CleanedEquipment"))
```

Comment: can this help You : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31813883/3279496

Comment: i believe ii will help that`s exactly my question...thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq to SQL select distinct and sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813713/linq-to-sql-select-distinct-and-sum)